# Displaying a single document from a mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, ejs

I use ejs to display the information but I am having trouble displaying only one document. I would like to display one document until user clicks the next button.

View:

```
<div>
    <h1>This is the movie page</h1>

    <ul>

        <% for(var i =0;  i < movies.length; i ++) {%>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Title:</span> <%= movies[i].DVD_Title %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Studio:</span> <%= movies[i].Studio %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Genre:</span> <%= movies[i].Genre %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Year:</span> <%= movies[i].Year %>
        </li>

        <br>
        <% } %>
        <button type="button" id="prev">Prev </button>
        <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var moviesModel = require("../models/movies");

/* GET /movies/ listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
moviesModel.find({}).where('Price').gt(10000).exec(function(err,movies){

    if(err) throw err;
    res.render('movies', {movies:movies});
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Link to my repo found [here](https://github.com/frfroylan/ramo).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the mongodb query data is returned to the view as an json objects I cannot increment it. I have to push it to its own array and increment that.

Here is my new view:

```
<div>
    <h1>This is the movie page</h1>

    <ul>

        <% var movieArray = new Array();
        for(var i =0;  i < movies.length; i ++) {
                movieArray.push(movies[i]);
        } 

        var x = 0;
        %>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Title:</span> <%= movieArray[x].DVD_Title %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Studio:</span> <%= movieArray[x].Studio %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Genre:</span> <%= movieArray[x].Genre %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Year:</span> <%= movieArray[x].Year %>
        </li>

        <br>

        <h1><%= movieArray.length %></h1>

        <button type="button" id="prev" onClick="prev_movie">Prev </button>
        <button type="button" id="next" onClick="next_movie">Next</button>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Once Prev or Next is pushed the x value will decrease or increase unless user reaches -1 or array.length.